# play mp4 within web page via silverlight or flash for a URL hosted on amazon S3

Tags: silverlight, flash, streaming, mp4

i need a webpage (host on my website) that can play the following mp4 file either via silverlight 4 or flash

https://s3.amazonaws.com/media.milpitastv.org/2011/Jan/helloworld.mp4

i tried various solution like flowplayer and silverlight but none of them work with the URL above. I can play the file fine using Windows media player or VLC.

For silverlight, i always get `AG_E_NETWORK_ERROR` exception within MediaFailed event. 
For flash, via flowplayer, IE page is just blank

Can someone tell me what am i missing? i am very frustrated as I have finished encoding, upload, cataloging my videos and now I am stuck at the last step.

Answer (score 0):

The encoding looks wrong to me.  Are you sure you are using the correct codec and parameters?  There is even an error message.

```
stu@manoa:~ $ ffmpeg -i helloworld.mp4 
FFmpeg version 0.6.1, Copyright (c) 2000-2010 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Dec 19 2010 11:41:10 with gcc 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5664)
  ...
[aac @ 0x12180f800]Transition from an ONLY_LONG or LONG_STOP to an EIGHT_SHORT sequence detected. If you heard an audible artifact, please submit the sample to the FFmpeg developers.

Seems stream 0 codec frame rate differs from container frame rate: 59.94 (60000/1001) -> 29.97 (2997/100)
    Last message repeated 1 times
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'helloworld.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : M4V 
    minor_version   : 1
    compatible_brands: M4V mp42isom
    show            : Government Access
    artist          : Government Access
    album           : Government Access
    genre           : TV Shows Public Affairs
    title           : Government Access 01-05-11 "Government Access"
    date            : 2011
  Duration: 00:05:01.03, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 759 kb/s
    Stream #0.0(eng): Video: h264, yuv420p, 320x240 [PAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], 628 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 29970 tbn, 59.94 tbc
    Stream #0.1(eng): Audio: aac, 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 128 kb/s
At least one output file must be specified
```